# Visual Studio 2010 Property Search

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In Visual studio 2010 Is there any extension to search for controls in tool box? Is there any way to filter properties of a control? There are lots of properties for a control for e.g. (Name, AcceptsReturn, AcceptsTab, AccibleName, Text, Visible, Top, Left etc.). I want to go directly to "Visible" property of the control. Is there any short cut or any extension?

Comment: What? Are you looking in the 'Properties' window while in the designer?

Comment: use Visual Studio 2012.there a search box for property window and for others(tool box,solution explorer...)

Comment: Yes **Jonesy** i am looking in "Properties" grid while in design mode.

Answer (score 0):

No there is nothing like that ..

If you have many control in your form and trying to set any specific property of all your controls like "Visible" property then you can select all your controls by holding shift or Ctrl key and change property value in property panel.

or if you want to change it 1 by 1 then

select your first control select property from property panel now type applicable property value
now on next control selection you need not to select property name again from property panel just type applicable property value it will change for respective control, dot net IDE will remember which property earlier you had selected.

Comment: I not looking for setting properties of multiple controls at a time but i am looking for setting property values easily in design time. i.e. short cut to go directly to specific row of property grid.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it with [Rapid Design](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c820e3a0-add2-4a43-943c-029e296ab00d)